# I can't seem to get my query times down

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I've done a search on google to figure out where to go to ask about query analysis, but everything brought me back to here. I apologize if I am wrong and this should go somewhere else.

Here are the current stats of my database (running Neo4j server v3.4):

[image: Database Info]

My Neo4jClient query:

```
var query = graphClient
                 .Cypher
                 .Match("(cp:CurrencyPair) - [:Currency_Pair] -> (mkt:MarketInfo)")
                 .With("mkt, cp")
                 .Where((CurrencyPair cp) => cp.Name == Pair.Name)
                 .AndWhere((MarketInfo mkt) => mkt.StartTicksUTC >= startTicks)
                 .AndWhere((MarketInfo mkt) => mkt.EndTicksUTC <= endTicks)
                 .With("mkt, cp")
                 .OrderBy("mkt.EndTicksUTC DESC")
                         .Match("(mkt) -[Ask_Input_Data] - (a:Ask)")
                         .With("mkt, cp, a")
                         .Match("(mkt) -[Bid_Input_Data] - (b:Bid)")
                         .With("mkt, cp, a, b")
                         .Return((mkt, cp, a, b) => new
                         {
                             MarketInfo = mkt.As<MarketInfo>(),
                             CurrencyPair = cp.As<CurrencyPair>(),
                             Ask = a.As<Ask>(),
                             Bid = b.As<Bid>()
                         });
```

Resulting Neo4j query:

```
profile 
MATCH (cp:CurrencyPair) - [Currency_Pair] -> (mkt:MarketInfo) 
WITH mkt, cp 
WHERE (cp.Name = "AUD/CAD") AND (mkt.StartUTC >= "2012-01-10T15:50:00+00:00" ) AND (mkt.StartUTC <= "2012-01-10T16:00:00+00:00" ) 
WITH mkt, cp 
ORDER BY mkt.EndTicksUTC DESC 

MATCH (mkt:MarketInfo) <-[Ask_Input_Data] - (a:Ask) 
WITH mkt, cp, a 
MATCH (mkt:MarketInfo) <-[Bid_Input_Data] - (b:Bid) 
WITH mkt, cp, a, b 

RETURN mkt AS MarketInfo, cp AS CurrencyPair, a AS Ask, b AS Bid
```

As you can see, I am trying to query the database to find all "MarketInfo" nodes that are related to a given currency node and then return nodes that are only between two dates.

Running this query, it takes 7 seconds to run:

[image: Query Breakdown]

and returns 10 nodes, 15 relationships

[image]

I do have indexes in the database:

Indexes

```
   ON :NewsEvent(Date) ONLINE

   ON :MarketInfo(EndTicksUTC) ONLINE

   ON :MarketInfo(EndUTC) ONLINE

   ON :MarketInfo(EndUTCTicks) ONLINE

   ON :NewsEvent(EventID) ONLINE 

   ON :Ask(Id) ONLINE 

   ON :Component(Id) ONLINE 

   ON :NewsEvent(Id) ONLINE 

   ON :MarketInfo(Id) ONLINE 

   ON :Bid(Id) ONLINE 

   ON :NewsEvent(Id, Date) ONLINE 

   ON :MarketInfo(Interval) ONLINE 

   ON :MarketInfo(Name) ONLINE 

   ON :MarketInfo(StartTicksUTC) ONLINE

   ON :MarketInfo(StartUTC) ONLINE 

   ON :MarketInfo(StartUTCTicks) ONLINE
```

Any thoughts on how I could speed this query up? Maybe I'm just going about this wrong? It's getting harder to sell my boss on Neo4j instead of using the "tried and true" MS SQL Server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made several major mistakes.

1. You separated your `WHERE` clause from the first `MATCH` clause with a superfluous `WITH` clause. That caused the `WHERE` clause to not filter the `MATCH` clause at all -- so it was finding **all** instances of the `(cp:CurrencyPair) - [:Currency_Pair] -> (mkt:MarketInfo)` pattern.
2. Your relationship types were not being specified at all, since you did not preceded their names with a colon. Therefore, **all** relationships between the nodes specified in your patterns were being matched.
3. You're missing an index on `:CurrencyPair(Name)`. (And do you really need every one of the other indexes? They introduce overhead when creating/deleting the relevant nodes.)

Here is a fixed version of your query that should run faster (especially after you add the index for `:CurrencyPair(Name)`):

```
    MATCH (cp:CurrencyPair) - [:Currency_Pair] -> (mkt:MarketInfo) 
    WHERE cp.Name = "AUD/CAD" AND
      "2012-01-10T15:50:00+00:00" <= mkt.StartUTC <= "2012-01-10T16:00:00+00:00"
    MATCH (mkt) <-[:Ask_Input_Data] - (a:Ask)
    MATCH (mkt) <-[:Bid_Input_Data] - (b:Bid)     
    RETURN mkt AS MarketInfo, cp AS CurrencyPair, a AS Ask, b AS Bid
    ORDER BY MarketInfo.EndTicksUTC DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll take a look at it and try to better my queries based off of your guidance. What I had done worked well for smaller datasets, which I tested on, so I had not considered the problems until now.

Another comment I should have made (and I edited the post to say) is I'm using Neo4jClient in C#, to do this...so sometimes trying to get the query into code isn't the easiest.

Comment: But WOW what a difference that query makes when executing it from the browser.

Comment: Getting your C# code to generate the same Cypher should be straightforward.